# Was it illegal to borrow my cousins trailer without his permission but leaving notes?

Tags: consent, family, borrowing

I borrowed my cousins utility trailer while he was at work. (Mine broke down with time-sensitive cargo on it and we borrow stuff from each other all the time.) I left him 3 notes explaining the dire situation, that it was me who took it and would return it in a few hours. Well he was drinking and blew the situation out of control and called the county sheriff dept. I was arrested. Was taking the trailer illegal since I left not one but 3 notes and we are family?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you live.

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

In Germany, some crimes are only prosecuted if the victim requests that, so-called *absolute Antragsdelikte*. Theft within a family is one of them ([§247 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__247.html)).

A few other crimes are prosecuted either on request or if the prosecutor sees a special public interest in bringing them to court, so-called *relative Antragsdelikte*. But most crimes are *Offizialdelikte,* they are prosecuted without regard to the wishes of the victim.

Comment: But do the acts described constitute a crime?

Comment: @phoog, as described, probably. The cousin did own the trailer, he did not give permission to take it, and the note possibly turns it from *theft* to *misappropriation*, but the judge would have to parse that line.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check the laws of your state, if you live in a country that has states, but in the US all states have particular laws regarding taking a motor vehicle without permission, for example [RCW 9A.56.070](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.56.070), however that requires an act resembling theft (e.g. attepting to sell, or altering appearance), and only applies to motor vehicles. If the trailer were a motor vehicle, then "joyriding" without permission would be a [lesser crime](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.56.075). It is also a crime to [borrow tools](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.56.096) with the intent to permanently keep. The law then states various conditions whereby one may assume an intend to keep, such as using fake ID on a rental contract, keeping more than 72 hours past the stipulated borrowing time.

It is legal for a person to report to the police that someone has taken their property, and the fact of being related does not make it illegal to report the action. It is legal for the police to arrest a person under suspicion of a crime if at the time reasonably trustworthy information that justifies believing that the person committed an offense (for instance, they are told "Smith stole my trailer").

It depends on your jurisdiction and all of the facts, but it does not seem that a crime was committed. It is, nevertheless, plausible that the officer had probable cause for the arrest. It would be illegal to file a false complaint, but a statement like "My cousin stole my trailer, I want him arrested" is, under the circumstances, not a provably false statement since the complainant would have to know that the taking did not legally constitute theft in that jurisdiction. You might argue that the officer should have inquired further into the circumstances, but it would be a high bar to clear to prove that the officer's belief that you committed a crime was unreasonable. However, a statement like "Well, I can arrest him to punish him, but it's not illegal to borrow a trailer under the circumstances" would be one way to clear that bar.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it’s illegal

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

[s154A](http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s154a.html) of the *Crimes Act* 1900 says:

> (1) Any person who--
>
> (a) without having the consent of the owner or person in lawful possession of a conveyance, takes and drives it, or takes it for the purpose of driving it, or secreting it, or obtaining a reward for its restoration or pretended restoration, or for any other fraudulent purpose, or
>
> (b) knowing that any conveyance has been taken without such consent, drives it or allows himself or herself to be carried in or on it,
>
> shall be deemed to be guilty of larceny and liable to be indicted for that offence.

This section captures what is colloquy  referred to as joyriding.

By your own admission, you knew you didn’t have permission and you took it and drove it. All the elements of the crime are there.